# pgAdmin edit data in result table

Tags: pgadmin-4

I need to change two fields in the resulting table.
I open Query Editor and execute a query.
All columns in the data table are read-only. How can I change them?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but thought the answer could help someone.
According to [the documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/editgrid.html): "each row in the table must be uniquely identifiable. If the table definition does not include an OID or a primary key, the displayed data is read only."

So you probably were viewing data from a table(s) without primary key defined.